# Ctrl-R to search backwards for shell commands in csh

Tags: shell, unix, csh, tcsh

I love this shortcut in borne shell, and want to find out if it is possible to simulate and/or have (perhaps to install an add-on or with a script) it  in  csh or tsch

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something that csh, tcsh, and even bash have is the **cool ! history substitution**.

This will run the last command starting with `cc`:

```
% !cc
```

This supplies the parameters from the last command:

```
% cc !*
```

This finds the last command that started with `cc` and substitutes its parameters:

```
% g++ !cc:*
```

This finds the last command that had `hello.c` anywhere in it:

```
% !?hello.c
```

Comment: This is not what the question is asking for. These could be useful for some, but definitely more dangerous than the backward-search the user is asking for.  We should change the accepted answer to haggai_e 's

Answer (score 76):

Try

```
bindkey "^R" i-search-back
```