# is there CTRL+R bash like search command for cshell?

Tags: csh

In **Bash** shell you can search through history commands with **CTRL+R** and typing just a **part** of the command and it can find it .

In **cshell** I know of **CTRL+P** that can search for commands that starts with the argument u give to him..

So Im wondering is there **CTRL+R** bash like search command for cshell ?

thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ctrl-R to search backwards for shell commands in csh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387357/ctrl-r-to-search-backwards-for-shell-commands-in-csh)

Comment: The original csh doesn't support Ctrl-P.  tcsh does. `/bin/csh` is often a symlink to `tcsh`, since it's mostly backward compatible, but if you want to use tcsh you should be explicit about it.